# Apache redirection to another port

Tags: apache, redirect, port

I'm in trouble with understanding the apache configuration to redirect an http to another.
I need to redirect the following:
http://test.com/foo to http://test.com:34567
and
http://test.com/bar to http://test.com:33490

I have seen that with that lines it redirects to another address, but I need to know if it will work before doing anything.

Redirect permanent "/foo" "http://test.com:34567"
Redirect permanent "/bar" "http://test.com:33490"

Thank you!

Comment: _“but I need to know if it will work before doing anything”_ - either you risk it and test this live (undo immediately, if it doesn’t work), or you set up a proper test system first …

Comment: Thank you CBroe, finally I tested it in https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works, If anyone wants, I tried it in https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/